# What I can do to speed up Key Lookup in my Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, index, execution-plan

I am using SQL2005 and against them I calling query simila to this

```
    declare @art table (id int primary key, naziv varchar(35) null, sifra varchar(15) null, jm int null);   

            insert into @art
            select id, left(naziv,35), left(sifra,15), jm from art a
            where   (a.id = @art_id@ or @art_id@ = 0 )

Select 
      s.art_id
     ,sum(kol) as kol
     ,sum(kol*mpc) as MPCI
     /*--and meny others --/
    from doc d 
                inner join dokumenti dk on (d.tip = dk.tip)
                inner join sdo s on (d.id=s.doc_id)
        where           
                        d.datum between  @do_datuma@ and @do_datuma@
                        and dk.prodaja = 1
                        and (dk.Mal_Vel in (@Mal_Vel@))
                        and (d.skl_id = @skl_id@ or (@skl_id@ = 0))
                        and ((d.skl_id in (select skl_id from skladiste_gruperj  where grp_id = @gr_rj_id@)) or ( @gr_rj_id@ = 0))
                        and (d.par_id = @par_id@ or @par_id@ = 0)
                        and s.art_id in (select id from @art)
            group by s.art_id
```

This is query is slow when  I take look at Execution plan I see that is Cost of 71 % is taken by
Key Lookup.

What I can do to seed up this query.

[image: This is how looks like my Execution plan]

Comment: See here some help: [Key Lookup Showplan Operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326635.aspx), [SQL SERVER – Query Optimization – Remove Bookmark Lookup – Remove RID Lookup – Remove Key Lookup](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/07/sql-server-query-optimization-remove-bookmark-lookup-remove-rid-lookup-remove-key-lookup/), [Showplan Operator of the Week - BookMark/Key Lookup](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---bookmarkkey-lookup/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove it by making the index [covering](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/)

That is, add an INCLUDE clause to the index so all columns needed are in the index.

Comment: Thank You so mach on fast post and also on all your answers. Which columns I do need to add after clause INCLUDE, Do I need to make Index with INCLUDE all output columns from table or only columns which is in filter (where).

Comment: @adopilot: you'll see what columns when you hover over the key lookup. I can't tell from the picture

Comment: @gbn did you try hovering over the picture?

Comment: @DTest: no. You hover over the execution plan in SSMS to get the columns. Not a picture of the plan on a webpage... The properties window in the image is chopped off too. How would you get the columns from this image?

Comment: I was being tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @DTest: A wee smiley might have helped. Or [some colour](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2001/02/01/the_color_of_irony/)